# Alternative to spring-mobile

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-mobile

I have a requirement where in all controllers I need to understand device type (desktop, mobile, tablet) and based on that I may need to send request to a different view. Right now, I have littered my controllers with duplicate code that does following:

1. Get User-Agent from HttpServletRequest
2. Find device type by matching User Agent string containing multiple pre-defined keywords in an array.
3. Use if/else statement to forward request to different view based on detected device type

To fix this I found out that spring-mobile is able to help with this. But unfortunately it looks like this project is abandoned. I am looking for a better alternative as a dependency or maybe a better design pattern to handle this problem.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Have you found any solution?

Comment: how do you find Device type with `HttpServletRequest`. As you have mentioned in `second step` that you matched `User-Agent containing pre-defined keywords`. What are those `Keywords`?